# Spring Data JPA: The data types varchar and varbinary are incompatible in the add operator exception occurs when using concat() method

Tags: java, sql-server, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

In my Spring Data project I am trying to use concat operation on JPA query annotation(shown below)

```
@Query("SELECT a from ApiEnrollmentsView a where (:mrn is null or a.mrn=:mrn) and " +
        " (:firstName is null  or a.firstName like concat(:firstName, '%')) and " +
        " (:lastName is null  or a.lastName like concat(:lastName, '%')) ")
List<ApiEnrollmentsView> findEnrollmentsByMrnAndFirstNameAndLastName(String mrn, String firstName, String lastName);
```

Project compiles fine but when I access the method, I get exception `data types varchar and varbinary are incompatible in the add operator`

**Exception:**

```
Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The data types varchar and varbinary are incompatible in the add operator.
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDatabaseError(SQLServerException.java:262)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.getNextResult(SQLServerStatement.java:1632)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.doExecutePreparedStatement(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:600)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement$PrepStmtExecCmd.doExecute(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:522)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.execute(IOBuffer.java:7225)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.executeCommand(SQLServerConnection.java:3053)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeCommand(SQLServerStatement.java:247)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeStatement(SQLServerStatement.java:222)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.executeQuery(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:444)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery(ProxyPreparedStatement.java:52)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery(HikariProxyPreparedStatement.java)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:57)
    ... 174 more
```

Comment: It did not work

Comment: Then I suspect that when string value is null then problems arise. You can use `COALESCE(:lastName, '')` inside concat

Comment: Not really, if I remove `concat()` and replace with `upper()` or `lower()` it works

Comment: instead of `concat` operator you could try `||`: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.3/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#hql-concatenation

Comment: @RobertNiestroj Hibernate docs specifically says not to use this https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/current/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#hql-concatenation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I remember I had exactly the same weird error. As it is mentioned in the comments the problem solved by using `coalesce` function instead of `concat`.

Comment: This fixed my issue. But I raised a bug report with Spring Data team regarding this. You can follow it here [DATACMNS-1778](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATACMNS-1778)

Answer (score 0):

use `COALESCE(:lastName, '')` inside `CONCAT`. It resolves my issue